# $\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{\frac{x^3}{6} +\sin x - x }{x^5}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, derivatives, fractions

Who can help me solving this limit?

> $$\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{\frac{x^3}{6} +\sin x - x }{x^5}$$

I don't need answer Taylor Maclaurin 
L'Hospital and Derivatives.  But I know my answer $\frac 1{120}$.

How can I do?

Comment: is this your formula?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Sorry because I just start to lern  it

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use *L'Hospital rule* $5$ times because each time we get $0/0$ form:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{5!} =  \frac{1}{5!}$$

Comment: Try to do it again

Comment: Don't use L'Hospital and Derivatives

Answer (score 1):

By L'Hospital we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{x^3}{6}+\sin{x}-x}{x^5}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+\cos{x}-1}{5x^4}=\frac{1}{10}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^2-4\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{x^4}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{10}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{x-2\sin\frac{x}{2}}{x^3}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{5}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos\frac{x}{2}}{3x^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{15}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{4}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{120}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{4}}{\frac{x^2}{16}}=\frac{1}{120}.$$

Comment: Sorry sir don't use L'Hospital  and Derivatives

Comment: Without Taylor or  L'Hospital or derivatives it's impossible I think.

Comment: I can do this the same to u

Comment: But I don't want

Comment: I used derivatives twice only instead five times.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I don't want to do this

Comment: U can help me . Don't do it by L'Hospital Taylor and Derivatives

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I agree with you, I have thought about this whole "no L'Hopital situation" and I think, this is one of those limits that cannot be done without L'Hospital or Taylor.

Comment: I want to sent photo to you now

Comment: I want to sent photo for you

Comment: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=192679514646404&id=100017130703735&fs=1&ref=wizard

Answer (score 1):

The limit can be proven using derivatives, and without l'Hopital's rule or series expansions as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=x^{1/2}+6\frac{\sin\left(x^{1/4}\right)}{x^{1/4}}
\\
f'(0)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^{1/2}+6\frac{\sin\left(x^{1/4}\right)}{x^{1/4}}-6}{x}&=6\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{x^3}{6}+\sin{x}-x}{x^5}
\end{aligned}
$$

Another way of approaching the problem is noticing is that the numerator contains the Maclaurin expansion of $\sin$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin(x)&\in x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\mathcal{O}(x^7)
\\
L&=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{x}-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)}{x^5}
\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(\color{red}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\ldots\right)-\left(\color{red}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}}\right)}{x^5}
&=\frac1{120}
\end{aligned}
$$

**@user45914123**'s answer shows an algebraic proof without using derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}L= \lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{\frac{x^3}{6} +\sin x - x }{x^5}&= \lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{\frac{x^3}{6} +3\sin(x/3) - 4 \sin^3(x/3) - x }{x^5} &\\&= \lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{x^3/6  -3(x/3)^3/6  - 4 \sin^3(x/3) }{x^5} &\\&+ \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{ 3(x/3)^3/6 +3\sin(x/3)-3(x/3)}{3^5(x/3)^5} &\\&= \dfrac{L}{3^4} + \lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{4(x/3)^3  - 4 \sin^3(x/3) }{x^5}&\\&= \dfrac{L}{3^4} &\\&+ \dfrac{4}{3^5}\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{((x/3)  -  \sin(x/3))( (x/3)^2 +\sin^2(x/3)+ (x/3) \sin(x/3)) }{(x/3)^5}&\\&=\dfrac{L}{3^4}+ \dfrac{2}{3^5}\end{align}$$

$$\therefore L  = \dfrac1{120}$$

Comment: Seems pretty slick; but how did you manage to show that $\lim \frac{(x/3\ldots)}{(x/3)^5}=1/2$?

Comment: Actually, I've answered my own question: $\lim {(x/3\ldots)}=\lim\frac{u-\sin(u)}{u^3}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2}+\frac{\sin u}{u}\right)$, for $u=x/3$. Then use math.stackexchange.com/questions/134051 .

Comment: @Jam Yes you are correct;  take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion for other such limits. Thanks for the upvote and mention in your answer. I shall return the favour.

Comment: You use seri Taylor again at sin x - x \approx x^3/6

Comment: @MasterAsk I don't see how or where I used used taylor. I would be glad if you enlighten me by telling me the step number. If you are asking about $\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{((x/3)  -  \sin(x/3))( (x/3)^2 +\sin^2(x/3)+ (x/3) \sin(x/3)) }{(x/3)^5}$, then take a look at second limit of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion.

Comment: The step number 2

Comment: The step number 2

Comment: @MasterAsk I used $\sin 3x = 3\sin x - 4\sin^3 x \iff\sin x = 3\sin (x/3) - 4\sin^3 (x/3)$

Answer (score 0):

It's $\sin(x)\sim x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{120}x^5,\, x\to0$. Can you take it from here?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html

Comment: Surely the Maclaurin series implicitly uses derivatives in its derivation, no?

Comment: Yes - just saw the heading. Sorry for that.